# What is the easiest way to get the current ETH price as an integer on an IoT device like the ESP8266

Tags: price

I am trying to build a contraption that shows the current ETH price on four 7-digit displays. For this, I obviously need to get the current ETH price to be able to display it.
The specific device I am using is the ESP8266 NodeMCU v1, and I am programming it with the Arduino IDE, so I am using some form of C++ if I'm not mistaken.
Something that I had found already that seemed to be simple enough was the coinmarketcap
API, found at https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/.
However, that API is no longer online.

As I am running the whole thing on a rather simple device, and am only interested in one single value, the ETH price, I would like to also keep the code behind it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use CoinGecko's API, one of the best out there.

You could make an HTTP GET request to the following endpoint to get the price of ETH quoted in USD:
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=ethereum&vs_currencies=usd

Also, you could learn how to make a GET request with an Arduino [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/59847/http-get-request-using-arduino-uno-and-esp8266).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!